# How can i solve this? Grafana Postgres

Tags: postgresql, grafana

So i was trying to do a code where i go and find the average of a time spent in a ticket, but i can´t do it, the problem is when i try to see the results i can´t because i need a time column and i can´t put one in whit the code i have.

This is my code:

```
SELECT AVG(lol) FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ticket_id)), SUM(time_spent_minutes) AS "lol", updated_on as "time"
FROM ticket_messages
WHERE admin_id IN ('20439','20457','20291','20371','20357','20235','20449','20355','20488')
GROUP BY updated_on, ticket_id) as m
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a nice example [here](https://medium.com/grafana-tutorials/graphing-non-time-series-sql-data-in-grafana-8a0ea8c55ee3) with the full explanation.

TLDR: add a `NOW()` column to your query

```
SELECT NOW() as tm, AVG(lol) FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ticket_id)), SUM(time_spent_minutes) AS "lol", updated_on as "time"
FROM ticket_messages
WHERE admin_id IN ('20439','20457','20291','20371','20357','20235','20449','20355','20488')
GROUP BY updated_on, ticket_id) as m
```